# HTML Template: вывести неэкранированные данные

Tags: html, golang

С помощью пакета [html/template](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) вызываю html-файл и передаю туда данные:

```
w := http.ResponseWriter //writer, куда пишем данные
tpl, _ := template.ParseFiles("/index.html") //шаблон, который вызываем
text := "<b>Bold</b> text" //строка, которую передаём
_ = tpl.Execute(w, text)
```

Если в шаблоне вызовем нашу строку через `{{ }}`, то фактически в DOM у нас будет строка:

```
&lt;b&gt;Bold&lt;/b&gt; text
```

То есть тег `<b>` был экранирован. Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы в переданной нами строке не применялось экранирование символов (то есть чтобы текст выводился полужирным)?

P.S. Например, в шаблонах Blade для Laravel для этого есть специальная команда `{!! !!}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте типизированные строки.  Точнее, 
[template.HTML](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template#HTML).
Пример:

```golang
_ = tpl.Execute(w, template.HTML(`<b>Hello</b>`))
```